# Find distinct elements based only on a part of the sentence in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```
name=c("PFLU_00001_gene", "PFLU_00001_mRNA", "PFLU_00001", 
       "PFLU_00002_gene", "PFLU_00002_mRNA", "PFLU_00002",
       "PFLU_00003_gene", "PFLU_00003_mRNA", "PFLU_00003")

type=c("gene", "mRNA","CDS","gene", "mRNA","CDS","gene", "mRNA","NA")

df <- data.frame(name, type)

             name type
1 PFLU_00001_gene gene
2 PFLU_00001_mRNA mRNA
3      PFLU_00001  CDS
4 PFLU_00002_gene gene
5 PFLU_00002_mRNA mRNA
6      PFLU_00002  CDS
7 PFLU_00003_gene gene
8 PFLU_00003_mRNA mRNA
9      PFLU_00003  NA
```

I would like from the column "*names*" to export the unique names
based only on the first part of the sentence (e.g., the PFLU_00001)

I would like my data to look like this.

```
name 
PFLU_00001
PFLU_00002
PFLU_00003
```

Any help and guidance are highly appreciated.

with best wishes,
LDT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_remove` to remove the `_` followed by one or more characters that are not a `_` (`[^_]+$`) at the end (`$`) of the string and specify a regex lookaround (`(?<=[0-9])`) so that it matches the `_` that follows a digit

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    transmute(name = str_remove(name, "(?<=[0-9])_[^_]+$")) %>% 
    distinct(name)
```

-output

```
#    name
#1 PFLU_00001
#2 PFLU_00002
#3 PFLU_00003
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Always amazing solutions. I ll accept the answer as soon as I can. Thank for providing me the explanation as well. I am getting there to understand the string replacement :|

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `unique` + `gsub`

```
unique(
  transform(
    df["name"],
    name = gsub("_\\D+$", "", name)
  )
)
```

gives

```
        name
1 PFLU_00001
4 PFLU_00002
7 PFLU_00003
```